# Как у телеграмм бота сделать так, чтобы после ответа на первый вопрос(нажатия кнопки) сразу появлялся второй вопрос

Tags: python, telebot

Вот выводит он мне первый вопрос, я, например, отвечаю 50, он пишет верно, а потом не выдает 2 вопрос. Как это пофиксить?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['play'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("15")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("32")
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("50")
    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сколько будет 25+25?', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def func(message):
    if (message.text == '50'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верно', reply_markup=a)

    elif (message.text == '32'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверно', reply_markup=a)

    elif (message.text == '15'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверно', reply_markup=a)
a = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("А")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Б")
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("В")
    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Какая буква первая?', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def func(message):
    if (message.text == 'А'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верно', reply_markup=a)

    elif (message.text == 'Б'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверно', reply_markup=a)

    elif (message.text == 'В'):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверно', reply_markup=a)
a = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
```

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['play'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
    markup.add("15", "32", "50")
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сколько будет 25+25?', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, input_number, "50")


def input_number(message, right_answer: str):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
    markup.add("А", "Б", "В")

    if message.text == right_answer:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верно', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверно', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Какая буква первая?', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, input_number, "А")


def input_str(message, right_answer: str):
    if message.text == right_answer:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Верно', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверно', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Если вас не затруднит, то опишите, как вы это сделали, буду очеееенннь благодарен!

Comment: bot.register_next_step_handler, это функция которая регистрирует хендлер который будет обрабатывать следующее сообщение от пользователя, ты передаешь туда название функции-обработчика и объект message, ну и в этом случае аргумент типа Правильный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо)! еще последний вопрос, а markup.add заменяет все 3 btn получается? Код в 3 строчки в 1 сократить круто.

Comment: Такой метод используется тогда когда вы не используете доп параметры в ReplyKeyboardButton. Если ответ вам подошел нажмите на "галочку" слева от ответа

Comment: Еще последний, уже точно, вопрос. (message, right_answer: str): зачем после right_answer ставится : и что значит str строка

Comment: Это аннотация, мы говорим что right_answer будет строкой. По нормальному нужно и message: types.Message писать. Это актуально особенно если вы пишите на IDE, вам будут выскакивать подсказки, какие операции можно сделать с обьектом/переменной или какие поля он в себе имеет